# Error installing node.js on google compute engine docker image

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup a node.js app inside docker, using as host the google compute engine VM gci-stable-55-8872-71-0 (debian), from image project google-containers:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create myvm --image-project google-containers --image gci-stable-55-8872-71-0  --zone europe-west1-b --machine-type f1-micro --scopes compute-rw
```

then I try to get a docker container running:

```
$ sudo docker build -t forperfuse/test .
```

but I keep getting errors when installing node:
    The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

all other dependencies install well but node and npm are not installing- I have tried several options but still cannot get it to work, can you please help? many thanks in advance...

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what is going on, looks like the run command in the dockerfile is aiming to a bash that has a weird header. If you can publish them we can try or...

You can use the bitnami docker image available in launcher for free and works like a charm.

https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher

And there search for the node.js image.

Comment: @DanV, glad to help. If you feel it was the solution, please mark it as accepted answer. Cheers!